# How to include GTK library for MuJoCo simulation in Visual Studio Code (Windows10)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gtk, mujoco

## What I'm trying to do

I'm practicing **MuJoCo simulation** based on the [YouTube lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1nCeqtfySQ&t=1646s) by Pranav Bhounsule.

In this lecture, the code for simulation is written in **C language**, and **makefile** for running the simulation is provided (as below).

```
    COMMON=/O2 /MT /EHsc /arch:AVX /I../../include /Fe../../bin/
    LIBS = ../../lib/glfw3dll.lib  ../../lib/mujoco.lib 
    CC = cl

    ROOT = project_name

    all:
        $(CC) $(COMMON) main.c $(LIBS) -o ../../bin/$(ROOT)

    main.o:
    $(CC) $(COMMON) -c main.c

    clean:
    rm *.o ../../bin/$(ROOT)
```

I have been working in Visual Studio 2022 and it worked fine until now.

Currently, I want to add GUI components by using **GTK-3.0 library** and I installed GTK-3.0 with vcpkg.

I've practiced some examples of GTK in Visual Studio 2022 and it worked fine.

And now, I'm trying to *add GTK libraries in my MuJoCo simulation code* so that I can integracte my simulation project in **Visual Studio Code** (I heard that using VSCode is better cause it is lightweight, versatile, ... and so on compared to IDE like VS2022).

## My Project Directory in detail

Basically, my MuJoCo project is constructed as below.
In the follwing directory, `C:/.../mujoco-2.2.1-windows-x86_64`

```
|-- include
|   |-- GLFW            // include GLFW headers e.g. glfw3.h, ...
|   |-- mujoco          // include mujoco headers e.g. mujoco.h, ...
|-- lib                 // include libraries e.g. glfw3dll.lib, mujoco.lib
|-- myProject
|   |-- project_name
|   |   |-- main.c      // this is the main code for MuJoCo simulation
|   |   |-- makefile    // makefile for complie as shown in above.
|   |   |-- run_win.bat // batch file for executing the simulation
```

Additionally, I installed GTK libraries using vcpkg in the following directory. `C:/.../vcpkg/installed/x64-windows`

```
|-- bin             // include GTK-related .dll files
|-- ...
|-- include         // include GTK-related header files
|   |-- atk-1.0
|   |-- cairo
|   |-- gtk-3.0
|       |-- gdk
|       |-- gtk     // gtk.h, ...
|   |-- ...
|-- lib             // include GTK-related .lib files
|   |-- gdk-pixbuf-2.0
|   |-- glib-2.0
|   |-- ...
|-- ...
```

## Problem Statement

As I mentioned above, I'm trying to include GTK libraries for my MuJoCo project in VSCode.
In the main.c, the relating headers are included as follows.

```
    #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
    #include <mujoco/mujoco.h>
    #include <gtk-3.0/gdk/gtk.h>
```

But, when I tired to run the simulation (even without including GTK libraries), error occurred in the terminal such that;

```
    gcc -c -g main.c ../../lib/glfw3dll.lib ../../lib/mujoco.lib
    main.c:9:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
        9 | #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
    compilation terminated.
```

(The similar error occurred for mujoco.h or gtk.h too.)

I guess it even can't find the directory for GLFW and mujoco headers (I don't know why).
I've included path for headers in [C/C++ Extension pack: IntelliSense Configurations] - [Include path] as below.

```
    ${workspaceFolder}/**
    C:\...\mujoco-2.2.1-windows-x86_64\include\**
    C:\...\mujoco-2.2.1-windows-x86_64\lib\**
    C:\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\**
    C:\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\**
```

(I didn't type '...' literally. '...' indicates the middle of the path I omitted. I actually typed all the path.)

I thought I did include the paths for including libraries and headers for GLFW, mujoco, and GTK correctly.
But terminal said it can't find such file or directory.

***So, I want to ask what did I missed or did wrong and what should I change in order to include GTK libraries and run the simulation correctly.***

## For Your Information

- When I practiced GTK examples in VS2022, I included all the .dll files, header files, and .lib files correctly in [Property Manager]-[VC++ Directories, C/C++, Linkger]. -> it worked fine.
- When I run the simulation in VS2022, I used 'cl' as a complier and 'nmake' for build the code and I typed 'run_win.bat' in the terminal in order to run the simulation.  -> it worked fine.
- In VSCode, I installed MinGW so as to use 'gcc' for a complier and editted batch file as below which build the code using 'mingw32-make'.

```
    mingw32-make
    SET var=%cd%
    cd ../../bin && quad_leg_floating
    cd %var%
```

- In [C/C++ Configurations], I chose [Compiler path] as 'C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe', and [IntelliSense mode] as 'windows-gcc-x64'.

As I mentioned previous,

When I practiced MuJoCo simulation in VS2022, with the specified makefile(with cl compiler), I can run the simulation by typing 'run_win.bat' in the terminal which commands 'nmake'.

Now, when I tried to run the same simulation in VSCode, I tried to use gcc as a complier and editted batch file 'mingw32-make' for build, but it didn't work.

I tried to add some settings in 'settings.json' as below, but it didn't work too.

```
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "C:/.../mujoco-2.2.1-windows-x86_64/include/mujoco",
        "C:/.../mujoco-2.2.1-windows-x86_64/include/GLFW"
     ]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are building a GUI, you can use the gui provided in mujoco, see the file simulate.c

Here is a barebones simulate file that you can modify. https://pab47.github.io/reports/MuJoCo%20UI%20Projectile%20Game.zip

Comment: Thank you for replying a comment and sharing example of creating GUI.

Actually, I complete creating GUI with GTK and matplotlibcpp libraries.

At the first moment, I thought native GUI functions of MuJoCo itself support basic features and I thought with external libraries, I can achieve further features.

But after I experienced lots of trial-and-errors, I realized it would be way easier and efficient to use MuJoCo functions. So, I'm planning to create GUI with those functions.

Anyway, I appreciate alot for your comments. I wish you have wonderful moments in 2024. Happy new year!